# explanation about the regressor score on neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, regression

I have a data base with only 340 lines, each with 53 predictive attributes, if I do the training through regression on neural network, I will get a correlation between data of 0.999, but, when I try to predict with different values, from the test database, the results are not good (the disparity between what is expected and what is obtained is huge). Does this correlation score indicates that the base has good attributes, and the results will get better if I increase the number of data, or for the results I already got,with values  far from what is expected, I can already conclude that even with the increase of data it wont get better? thanks

Comment: This sounds similar to over fitting, so my suggestion would be to try a less complex neural network with fewer nodes. As an experiment, try reducing the number of neurons by half.

Comment: adding to @JamesPhillips how is the correlation between the original data and the output variables ? else a single layer (53 input followed by a sinngle layer with multiple neurons, might do the job, if high correlation in predictor variables)